# Shortcuts for phrases

Tags: key-bindings

What is the appropriate way to make shortcuts for phrases like ‘on the other hand’? I tried `imap otoh on the other hand`, but that produces an undesireable lag after all `o`s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `:help abbreviations`:

```
iabbrev otoh on the other hand
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) generic snippet plugin. In this you can do something like.

```
snippet otoh "Some description" b
on the other hand
endsnippet
```

Comment: This is like using a ballistic missile to kill a mouse.  Vim has builtin support for abbreviations.

Comment: No harm done when you atleast know that you kill a mouse a by that :)